# How to setup notifications in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications, background-application

I was wondering if Flutter has the ability to generate push notifications from within the app. If so is there a code example of this?

Description:
An event occurs on the flutter app such as a button being clicked or an if statement being triggered, I want a push notification sent to the user.

The app should also always be running in the background, is this possible? If so can you provide me a link with an example of this implementation.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

I have looked on google but I haven't been able to find a lot of information regarding these two topics.

Answer (score 0):

Being an iOS engineer, I'd say that you actually want *local notifications*. Push notifications are usually being sent by a server.

You could check how it's usually done on iOS natively: [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app).